# Should I override hashCode() of Collections?

Tags: java, collections, hashcode

Given that I some class with various fields in it:

```
class MyClass {
    private String s;
    private MySecondClass c;
    private Collection<someInterface> coll;
    // ...

    @Override public int hashCode() {
        // ????
    }
}
```

and of that, I do have various objects which I'd like to store in a `HashMap`. For that, I need to have the `hashCode()` of `MyClass`.

1. I'll have to go into all fields and respective parent classes *recursively* to make sure they all implement `hashCode()` properly, because otherwise `hashCode()` of `MyClass` might not take into consideration some values. Is this right?
2. What do I do with that `Collection`? Can I always rely on its `hashCode()` method? Will it take into consideration all child values that might exist in my `someInterface` object?

---

I OPENED A SECOND QUESTION regarding the actual problem of uniquely IDing an object here: [How do I generate an (almost) unique hash ID for objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169524/how-do-i-generate-a-almost-unique-hash-id-for-objects)

---

Clarification:

> is there anything more or less unqiue in your class? The String s? Then only use that as hashcode.

MyClass hashCode() of two objects should definitely differ, if any of the values in the `coll` of one of the objects is changed. HashCode should only return the same value if all fields of two objects store the same values, resursively. Basically, there is some time-consuming calculation going on on a MyClass object. I want to spare this time, if the calculation had already been done with the exact same values some time ago. For this purpose, I'd like to look up in a HashMap, if the result is available already.

> Would you be using MyClass in a HashMap as the key or as the value? If the key, you have to override both equals() and hashCode()

Thus, I'm using the hashCode OF MyClass as the *key* in a HashMap. The value (calculation result) will be something different, like an Integer (simplified).

> What do you think equality should mean for multiple collections? Should it depend on element ordering? Should it only depend on the absolute elements that are present?

Wouldn't that depend on the kind of Collection that is stored in `coll`? Though I guess ordering not really important, no

The response you get from this site is gorgeous. Thank you all

> @AlexWien that depends on whether that collection's items are part of the class's definition of equivalence or not.

Yes, yes they are.

Comment: What do you think equality should _mean_ for multiple collections?  Should it depend on element ordering?  Should it only depend on the absolute elements that are present?

Comment: Most probably in your case you would not override hashCode().

Comment: is there anything more or less unqiue in your class? The String s? Then only use that as hashcode.

Comment: Would you be using `MyClass` in a `HashMap` as the *key* or as the *value*? If the key, you have to override both `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Comment: If you need to override `hashCode` and `equals` for `MyClass`, you should probably not have a field of type `Collection`. You should probably use `List` or `Set` instead.

Comment: @Blauhim How big are the collections you are using? If the size is small there is no problem using `hashCode`.

Comment: "if any of the values in its coll is changed." When they change is that a new object., or do they change in runtime of the same object? Hashcode must be imutable!

Comment: @AlexWien of course NOT; if an object is mutable, its hashCode() maychange, that stands to reason. But then you should be _very_ wary about using such objects in collections to start with.

Comment: No, don't use the hashCode of your class as the key. It is *not* unique.

Comment: If the collection's items are "part of the class's definition" the field should not be of type `Collection` because there is nothing in that interface's contract that says that `hashCode` or `equals` depend on the values in the `Collection`. `List` and `Set`, on the other hand, do guarantee this.

Comment: Alex, you're making up requirements. The API docs do not require hash codes to be immutable. "Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently return the same integer, **provided no information used in equals comparisons on the object is modified.**" ([source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--))

Comment: @Blauhim show us the implementation of `equals` you want to use, and from that we can figure out what a correct implementation of `hashCode` is.

Comment: I ask you again: Is the content of the collectiion fixed and will it never change anymore after object creation?

Comment: @JohnKugelman yes, this is the meaning of immutable hashcode: the hashcode will not change anymore (for that fields that are used in equals)

Comment: @AlexWien you obviously 1. either want to belittle people, or 2. do not understand hashCode very well (see John's reply)

Comment: @AlexWien no changes at all after object creating.

Comment: It means the hash code must be consistent from call to call, unless you change a field use in `equals()`, in which case the hash code can change. You are probably thinking of `Map`'s requirement that keys be immutable: "Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is a key in the map." ([Source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)) Note that this applies even to `TreeMap`s which don't use hash codes.

Comment: Your design  is a bit untypical for an object that overrides hashcode().Why do you want that? Do you expect a speed up? Do you realy need the equals() dependent of content? or do you just want to store your object in a map, to retreive them later?

Comment: @LouisWasserman tbh I don't intend to use equals on MyClass at all.. I just thought I could use hashCode() for (not 100% tho) unique distinction. If I understand right, I shouldn't be using any Collection fields then

Comment: @Blauhirn `hashCode` doesn't provide unique distinction. E.g. the set `[1, 4]` has the same `hashCode` as the set `[2, 3]`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Yes, but he wants to use a map. Now it is interesting what he wants to  use as key. I thought he wants to use the object instance and therefore  hashCode() as key, As he wrote in his first sentence

Comment: How many object you will have in that map: ten, hundreds, thousands?

Comment: @AlexWien please have a look at the updated post, I wrote some things about key/value usage and and sense of all of this prior. How many in that map? about 20-100, I guess.

Comment: @PaulBoddington yes you are right. What do I do then? recursive md5-hash on all fields?

Comment: I've never heard of an md5-hash, I'm afraid. I've never encountered this issue of needing to make `hashCode` recursive. Normally, I just use a `List<X>` or a `Set<X>` where I know that the type `X` has correctly implemented `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Yes, Now i have enough infor,mation

Comment: @Blauhirn - another clarification, please: I'm viewing the situation as new objects coming in which need the "big calculation" to be done, and some of these new objects have the same values as objects that you have already processed. Is that correct? Do you  keep the old objects around? Do their values change at all, and if they do, does it affect the data that should appear in the `HashMap`?

Comment: @Blauhim, if you need uniqueness, then no hashing algorithm will do.  You must use the actual objects, and you must use equals.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 1. I'll have to go into all fields and respective parent classes *recursively* to make sure they all implement `hashCode()` properly, because otherwise `hashCode()` of `MyClass` might not take into consideration some values. Is this right?

That's correct. It's not as onerous as it sounds because the rule of thumb is that you only need to override `hashCode()` if you override `equals()`. You don't have to worry about classes that use the default `equals()`; the default `hashCode()` will suffice for them.

Also, for your class, you only need to hash the fields that you compare in your `equals()` method. If one of those fields is a unique identifier, for instance, you could get away with just checking that field in `equals()` and hashing it in `hashCode()`.

All of this is predicated upon you also overriding `equals()`. If you haven't overridden that, don't bother with `hashCode()` either.

> 2. What do I do with that `Collection`? Can I always rely on its `hashCode()` method? Will it take into consideration all child values that might exist in my `someInterface` object?

Yes, you can rely on any collection type in the Java standard library to implement `hashCode()` correctly. And yes, any `List` or `Set` will take into account its contents (it will mix together the items' hash codes).

Comment: Most probably this apporach will not make sense for his application

Comment: Callsing hashCode() for the Collection which iterates and calls hashcode() on the child will cost much more perfomance than just using the default implementtaion of hahcode(). You don't need the content of the Collection to have a suitable hashcode. And worse if the content of the collections change, inbetween hashCode() calls, will break the java hashmaps.

Comment: @AlexWien that depends on whether that collection's items are part of the class's definition of equivalence or not.

Comment: I doubt that they are part of a sensfull equality definition. And event when it would so, it would still make no sense. hashCode() dont have to be unique.

Comment: Is this why I got a downvote? I don't understand your comment. Collection classes already hash their contents. That's what they do already, the OP doesn't have to do it himself. For instance, `AbstractList.hashCode()` looks like `int hashCode = 1; for (E e : this)  hashCode = 31*hashCode + (e==null ? 0 : e.hashCode()); return hashCode;`.

Comment: We don't know anything about whether the collection's contents are part of this class's definition of equivalence; that's for OP to determine; but if they are, they should be included in its hash code.

Comment: I downvoted: Imagine you have 10.000 elements in that collection. Would you be so stupid to let it call hashcode on all elements. Horrible!

Comment: `Collection` does not mandate that `equals` and `hashCode` check the contents, but `List` and `Set` do. Which means that in practice most collections do check their contents.

Comment: @AlexWien That's what `AbstractList` and `AbstractSet` do.

Comment: Yes AbstractList, etc. they do, but you pay  the performance, so don't calls hahscode on Collections. You dont need that. If you have a unique id, fine, use that, if you dont have, use the default hashCode()  and dont overide equals in the OP special case.

Comment: @JohnKugelman thanks John, I appreciate the way you handle people around these sites. (Seems the actual problem for me lies somewhere else.. created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169524/how-do-i-generate-an-almost-unique-hash-id-for-objects?noredirect=1#comment54147001_33169524)

Answer (score 2):

So you want to do a calculation on the contents of your object that will give you a unique key you'll be able to check in a `HashMap` whether the "heavy" calculation that you *don't* want to do twice has already been done for a given deep combination of fields.

## Using `hashCode` alone:

I believe `hashCode` is not the appropriate thing to use in the scenario you are describing.

`hashCode` should *always* be used in association with `equals()`. It's part of its contract, and it's an important part, because `hashCode()` returns an integer, and although one may try to make `hashCode()` as well-distributed as possible, it is not going to be unique for every possible object of the same class, except for very specific cases (It's easy for `Integer`, `Byte` and `Character`, for example...).

If you want to see for yourself, try generating strings of up to 4 letters (lower and upper case), and see how many of them have identical hash codes.

`HashMap` therefore uses both the `hashCode()` and `equals()` method when it looks for things in the hash table. There will be elements that have the same `hashCode()` and you can only tell if it's the same element or not by testing all of them using `equals()` against your class.

## Using `hashCode` and `equals` together

In this approach, you use the object itself as the key in the hash map, and give it an appropriate `equals` method.

To implement the `equals` method you need to go deeply into all your fields. All of their classes must have `equals()` that matches what you think of as equal for the sake of your big calculation. Special care needs to be be taken when your objects implement an interface. If the calculation is based on calls to that interface, and different objects that implement the interface return the same value in those calls, then they should implement `equals` in a way that reflects that.

And their `hashCode` is supposed to match the `equals` - when the values are equal, the `hashCode` must be equal.

You then build your `equals` and `hashCode` based on all those items. You may use `Objects.equals(Object, Object)` and `Objects.hashCode( Object...)` to save yourself a lot of boilerplate code.

But is this a good approach?

While you can cache the result of `hashCode()` in the object and re-use it without calculation as long as you don't mutate it, you can't do that for `equals`. This means that calculation of `equals` is going to be lengthy.

So depending on how many times the `equals()` method is going to be called for each object, this is going to be exacerbated.

If, for example, you are going to have 30 objects in the `hashMap`, but 300,000 objects are going to come along and be compared to them only to realize that they are equal to them, you'll be making 300,000 heavy comparisons.

If you're only going to have very few instances in which an object is going to have the same `hashCode` or fall in the same bucket in the `HashMap`, requiring comparison, then going the `equals()` way may work well.

If you decide to go this way, you'll need to remember:

**If the object is a key in a `HashMap`, it should *not* be mutated** as long as it's there. If you need to mutate it, you may need to make a deep copy of it and keep the copy in the hash map. Deep copying again requires consideration of all the objects and interfaces inside to see if they are copyable at all.

## Creating a unique key for each object

Back to your original idea, we have established that `hashCode` is not a good candidate for a key in a hash map. A better candidate for that would be a hash function such as `md5` or `sha1` (or more advanced hashes, like sha256, but you don't need cryptographic strength in your case), where collisions are a lot rarer than a mere `int`. You could take all the values in your class, transform them into a byte array, hash it with such a hash function, and take its hexadecimal string value as your map key.

Naturally, this is not a trivial calculation. So you need to think if it's really saving you much time over the calculation you are trying to avoid. It is probably going to be faster than repeatedly calling `equals()` to compare objects, as you do it only once per instance, with the values it had at the time of the "big calculation".

For a given instance, you could cache the result and not calculate it again unless you mutate the object. Or you could just calculate it again only just before doing the "big calculation".

However, you'll need the "cooperation" of all the objects you have inside your class. That is, they will all need to be reasonably convertible into a byte array in such a way that two equivalent objects produce the same bytes (including the same issue with the interface objects that I mentioned above).

You should also beware of situations in which you have, for example, two strings "AB" and "CD" which will give you the same result as "A" and "BCD", and then you'll end up with the same hash for two different objects.

Comment: Thank you for all your time, you seem to understand what I wasn't able to express. "You could take all the values in your class, transform them into a byte array" - yes, that's the right way, I think. Just so you got a proper idea: 1 calculation may take 40 seconds. 1 MyClass object is 60 MB big. 1 result = ~100 KB. Bc of the size of the original objects, it doesn't look like I can store them directly in the hashMap for comparison. / Again, "transform [all your values in your class] to a byte array" - how do I do that?? Manually in MyClass.hash()? This looks sooo much like .hashCode() to me

Comment: Your answer doesn't actually answer the questions I asked, although it includes everything I wanted to know. So maybe I should open another question, asking for 'how to generate a unique key for my object'. Would you post your answer there another time?

Comment: @Blauhirn Well, if you create that question, then I'll just explain the unique key part and refrain from the `hashCode`/`equals` explanation, which will not be pertinent for that question. If you do write this question, be sure to explain the whole situation - where are the objects coming from, what is their lifetime cycle, etc. For example, putting an object in a map doesn't make a copy (unless you explicitly deep copy it), so if you were intending to keep it around anyway, you are not paying for it in memory. But if you don't keep it around, it's a different situation.

Comment: Here it is! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33169524/how-do-i-generate-a-almost-unique-hash-id-for-objects

Answer (score 0):

For future readers.

Yes, equals and hashCode go hand in hand.

Below shows a typical implementation using a helper library, but it really shows the "hand in hand" nature.  And the helper library from apache keeps things simpler IMHO:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    MyCustomObject castInput = (MyCustomObject) o;

    boolean returnValue = new org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.EqualsBuilder()
            .append(this.getPropertyOne(), castInput.getPropertyOne())
            .append(this.getPropertyTwo(), castInput.getPropertyTwo())
            .append(this.getPropertyThree(), castInput.getPropertyThree())
            .append(this.getPropertyN(), castInput.getPropertyN())
            .isEquals();

    return returnValue;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.HashCodeBuilder(17, 37)
            .append(this.getPropertyOne())
            .append(this.getPropertyTwo())
            .append(this.getPropertyThree())
            .append(this.getPropertyN())
            .toHashCode();
}
```

17, 37 .. those you can pick your own values.

Answer (score -1):

From your clarifications:

You want to store `MyClass` in an `HashMap` as key.
This means the `hashCode`() is not allowed to change after adding the object.
So if your collections may change after object instantiation, they should not be part of the hashcode().

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

> Note: great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as map
>   keys. The behavior of a map is not specified if the value of an object
>   is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the
>   object is a key in the map.

For 20-100 objects it is not worth that you enter the risk of an inconsistent hash() or equals() implementation.

There is no need to override hahsCode() and equals() in your case.
If you don't overide it, java takes the unique object identity for equals and hashcode() (and that works, epsecially because you stated that you  don't need an equals() considering the values of the object fields).

When using the default implementation, you are on the safe side.

Making an error like using a custom hashcode() as key in the HashMap when the hashcode changes after insertion, because you used the hashcode() of the collections as part of your object hashcode may result in an extremly hard to find bug.

If you need to find out whether the heavy calculation is finished, I would not **absue equals()**. Just write an own method `objectStateValue()` and call hashcode() on the collection, too. This then does not interfere with the objects hashcode and equals().

```
public int objectStateValue() {
    // TODO make sure the fields are not null;
 return 31 * s.hashCode() + coll.hashCode();
}
```

Another simpler possibility: The code that does the time consuming calculation can raise an calculationCounter by one as soon as the calculation is ready.  You then just check whether or not the counter has changed. this is much cheaper and simpler.

Comment: You're assuming that equal objects are the same object. If that was so, then the whole situation wouldn't arise. I believe OP wants to do an equivalence-based mapping because different instances that have the same values are likely to occur.

Comment: As I  understood the  OP does not need equals(). And you are right the whole sitaution will not arise.

Comment: OP doesn't want to implement `equals()` (whether that is justified or not remains to be seen), but needs to find out if a heavy calculation was already done for a given combination of fields. This suggests that new objects that have the same combinations of fields may occur during the operation of the program.

Comment: OP stated: "tbh I don't intend to use equals on MyClass at all.. I just thought I could use hashCode() for (not 100% tho) unique distinction. "

Comment: @RealSkeptic Ist not a good idea to use hashcode as key in a Map (as he stated) when he would need equals()  to consider the collection. probably the whole design is not yet ideal. To find out  whether something on the object has changed he might call the hashcode of the collection, but bnot as part of his equals()

Comment: OP may be mistaken in the choice of proper implementation, but the statement of the problem was: _Basically, there is some time-consuming calculation going on on a MyClass object. I want to spare this time, if the calculation had already been done with the exact same values some time ago. For this purpose, I'd like to look up in a HashMap, if the result is available already._

Comment: Yes, see my last comment (which apeared while you had typed). To find out if something ha schanged he needs an somethingChanged() method. because equals() and hashcode() have a strong contract to be fullfilled. And that Map contract will be broke when the hashcode is based on the collection, (It would be possible to use the collection only in equals, and not in hashcode()) But still  then the somethingChanged() method is safer()

Comment: I updated to handle the detection of something changed